# How to use NSolve or Solve with lists for variables?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve this expression:

```
NSolve[Qforced == hFree*SA*(Tskin - T), T]
```

but Qforced and hFree are lists of variables but same size, ex: {1,2,3,4...};

I am getting an empty solution "{ }" but if I do:

```
NSolve[Qforced[[1]] == hFree[[1]]*SA*(Tskin - T), T]
```

I get an answer. What I would like to do is this (written in Java):

```
ArrayList answerSets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>;
for (int i = 0; i < Qforced.size(),i++ ){
  ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double.
  for (int j = 0; k < hFree.size()){
    double Q = Qforced.get(i);
    double h = hFree.get(j);
    double T = -(Q/(h*SA)) - Tskin;
    temp.add(T);
  }
  answerSets.add(temp);
}
```

answerSets would be an arraylist of length Q.size(), each element being an arraylist of Q.size() containing the solution to the expression "T = -(Q/(h*SA)) - Tskin"

I would hate to write NSolve Qforced^2 times.
I've come across this problem a lot and I can't seem to find any documentation that explains what I want to do.  Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to solve the equation for all possible combinations of the indices? If so you can use [`Outer[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html) to avoid writing the equation N^2 times

```
Outer[NSolve[#1 == #2 * SA * (Tskin - T), T]&, Qforced, hFree]
```

If you need to pick out just certain parts of the output that `NSolve` gives you (in case there are multiple solutions), you can change `NSolve[...]&` to `NSolve[...][[part]]&` where `part` is a [`Part[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) specificaltion.

Comment: Just realized it doesn't include units.. say I'm solving for a slope a*x+b.  a should be in m/s^2 and b should be in m/s.  Is there any way to do that?  The input parameters have units.

Using Mathematica 9

Comment: Units are inbuilt into Mathematica. Take a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Units.html